# In how many ways can an inspector visit $4$ normal sites and $1$ "suspicious" one?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I cannot figure out why my answer to the following question is wrong:

> Suppose that a weapons inspector must inspect each of five different sites twice, visiting one site per day. The inspector is free to select the order in which he visits these sites, but cannot visit site $X$, the most suspicious site, on two consecutive days. In how many ways can the inspector visit these sites?

The set of sites is $$S=\{a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, X, X \}$$

The set of sites where the inspector visits $X$ on consecutive days is 
$$R=\{a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, (X, X) \}$$

My idea is to do $$\text{number of distinguishable permutations of S}-\text{number of distinguishable permutations of R}$$

$$\dfrac {10!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!\cdot 2!}-\dfrac {9!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 1!}$$

However, the right answer is $90,720$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks right to me! Maybe I am making the same error?

Comment: What's the right answer? Maybe that could lead people to a solution.

Comment: @Arthur It should not,  because in the second case you are treating the  the set of two visits to site $X$ as one object.

Comment: @Stefan4024 It's 90,720, I've updated the question too

Comment: @Ovi Are you sure that you computed your expression correctly? It evaluates to 90720.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee it's about 300,000 according to WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10!%2F(2*5)-9!%2F(2*4)

Comment: But also your answer is 90,720

Comment: @Stefan4024 Please see the wolfram alpha link

Comment: In the denominator it should be $2^5$ instead of $2*5$. Your not adding the 2's, you are multiplying them

Comment: @Stefan4024 OH! haha my mistake

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10!%2F(2%5E5)-9!%2F(2%5E4)

Comment: @Ovi You should answer your own question so that there is some closure on the matter :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Okay :P

Comment: @AndréNicolas Please see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer looks OK. Simplifying a little:
$$\dfrac {10!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!\cdot 2!}-\dfrac {9!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 1!} = \left(\frac{10}{2}-1\right)\frac{9!}{2^{4}} = 4\cdot\frac{9!}{16} = \frac{9!}{4}$$

Using a different approach, consider placing the low priority sites in order:
$$\frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$$

Then the bad site visits slot into the $9$ "gaps" in ${9\choose 2}$ ways:
$$\frac{8!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}{9\choose 2} = \frac{8!}{16} \cdot\frac{9\cdot8}{2} =\frac{9!}{4} $$

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the OP, $\dfrac {10!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!\cdot 2!}-\dfrac {9!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 1!}$, correctly evaluates to $90, 720$. I had repeatedly made a computation mistake when evaluating this, which led me to believe it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is correct and does evaluate to 90720.